# Changes won't show up in the browser when refreshed

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, visual-studio-code, view, page-refresh

Just started to develop with angularjs and created my first applications but anytime i change something in html files it won't show until i run the project by the "run" option of visual code studio. I created the applications with `ng new my-app` and i'm not sure if i'm missing something.

I tried to follow this tutorial on youtube: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G0bBLvWXBvc)

but the developer didn't had the same issue, i tried:

- DevTools->Network->Disable Cache
- `ng serve --watch --live-reload` and `ng serve --live-reload`

### Solved

It was my first time using VSC and i didn't knew that the option of auto save of a file was setted off by default, so i used `ctrl + s` to save the file and now it's working, i also changed the default options to save the file whenever i change windows

Answer (score 0):

If you started the application with `ng serve` it should recompile automatically by default.

In the documentation of Angular, `ng serve` has a parameter `--live-reload` that you can add, I guess you can try that. More info on https://angular.io/cli/serve

Start your application with `ng serve --live-reload` and it should work as expected (default is true).

Edit: The above code reloads the page on change.
You may have to add `--watch` as well, which would watch for changes.

Making the command `ng serve --watch --live-reload`

Comment: I tried both but it's still not working, thanks anyways

Comment: Maybe it would be useful to add that information to your post and possibly the tutorial you were following?

Comment: yes i will add!